# NSComboBox focus ring is not aligned correctly

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder

When I create a NSComboBox and I set the control size to small, the focus ring is not aligned correctly.
I noticed the same problem in the xcode interface (cfr. screenshot).

Your help is welcome.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. How could they allow this ugly focus ring to be part of the UI!?

Comment: The problem is solved in OSX 10.11 El Capitan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reported this today on [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com) as Radar #[20852031](http://rdar://problem/20852031)

My workaround is to subclass NSComboBoxCell:

```
- (void)drawFocusRingMaskWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame inView:(NSView *)controlView
{
    NSRect          focusRect   = cellFrame;

    focusRect.origin.y      += 1.0f;
    focusRect.size.width    -= 3.0f;
    focusRect.size.height   -= 5.0f;

    //  NSBezierPath *focusPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:focusRect
    //                                                            xRadius:2.0f
    //                                                            yRadius:2.0f];

    NSBezierPath    *focusPath  = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    CGFloat         leftRadius  = 2.0f;
    CGFloat         rightRadius = 5.0f;

    [focusPath moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(focusRect.origin.x + leftRadius, focusRect.origin.y)];

    [focusPath lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(focusRect.origin.x + focusRect.size.width - rightRadius, focusRect.origin.y)];
    [focusPath curveToPoint:NSMakePoint(focusRect.origin.x + focusRect.size.width, focusRect.origin.y + rightRadius)
              controlPoint1:NSMakePoint(focusRect.origin.x + focusRect.size.width, focusRect.origin.y)
              controlPoint2:NSMakePoint(focusRect.origin.x + focusRect.size.width, focusRect.origin.y)];

    [focusPath lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(focusRect.origin.x + focusRect.size.width, focusRect.origin.y + focusRect.size.height - rightRadius)];
    [focusPath curveToPoint:NSMakePoint(focusRect.origin.x + focusRect.size.width - rightRadius, focusRect.origin.y + focusRect.size.height)
              controlPoint1:NSMakePoint(focusRect.origin.x + focusRect.size.width, focusRect.origin.y + focusRect.size.height)
              controlPoint2:NSMakePoint(focusRect.origin.x + focusRect.size.width, focusRect.origin.y + focusRect.size.height)];

    [focusPath lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(focusRect.origin.x + leftRadius, focusRect.origin.y + focusRect.size.height)];
    [focusPath curveToPoint:NSMakePoint(focusRect.origin.x, focusRect.origin.y + focusRect.size.height - leftRadius)
              controlPoint1:NSMakePoint(focusRect.origin.x, focusRect.origin.y + focusRect.size.height)
              controlPoint2:NSMakePoint(focusRect.origin.x, focusRect.origin.y + focusRect.size.height)];

    [focusPath lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(focusRect.origin.x, focusRect.origin.y + leftRadius)];
    [focusPath curveToPoint:NSMakePoint(focusRect.origin.x + leftRadius, focusRect.origin.y)
              controlPoint1:NSMakePoint(focusRect.origin.x, focusRect.origin.y)
              controlPoint2:NSMakePoint(focusRect.origin.x, focusRect.origin.y)];

    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    {
        [focusPath fill];
    }
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];
}
```

Comment: Nice attention to detail! I wonder if this WWDC will be the one when NSCell is depreciated?

Comment: For me, I found it was slightly better aligned with `focusRect.size.height   -= 3.0f;`